# Why is my tty green?

Tags: tty

I have KUbuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

graphics card (lshw): GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]

driver: nvidia 390.116

4k monitor: BenQ EL2870U

The monitor is connected via HDMI (the cable is 4k ready). But it is the same with DVI.

If I connect the monitor to a different PC (same OS) then the tty is normal (black).

If I connect a different monitor to the first PC then the tty is normal too.

Maybe it's related to the 4K resolution?

The desktop is showing correctly.

Maybe it's because the tty has a low color depth?

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoFSx.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. That green is weird, but can be provide a bit more info regarding your setup to help others diagnose this. Such as, computer, monitor and cable used. Have you tried the Live CD and do you also get the green background when you drop to console from the live CD.

Comment: When booting from USB (same OS) I get a black screen after the KUbuntu logo. The Monitor says "no signal". Also can't go into the tty (screen stays black).

Comment: That is very strange that only this particular combination of monitor on this computer gives you this green screen. Your accessment may be correct that this PC and monitor is causing the console to render in 4K resulting in green console. Is your HDMI cable capable of doing 4K resolution?

Comment: The HDMI cable is 4k ready. The desktop is showing correctly. Maybe it's because the tty has a low color depth.

Comment: One other thing you could try is to reconfigure the console by using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` See if changing the various display mode at the end of the configuration will help. I think you might have to reboot to see the new setting as it changes initrd.img which is used during bootup.

Comment: At the end of the configuration it asks me for the size of the font. I tried different sizes and also sizes with the appendix "framebuffer only". But the background color stays green.

Comment: Bummer, probably the font changes does not forces it to change resolution of the console. Perhaps you can try changing the resolution fo the console via boot parameter to see if it makes a different. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution on how this can be done.

Comment: I went into grub and listed the available video modes using "videoinfo". Then I added "GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768" to the end of /etc/default/grub and ran "update-grub" and "update-grub2". Then I rebooted. The tty is still green and in the monitor menu I can see that the resolution of the tty is still 3840 × 2160.

Comment: One last thing I can suggest is that you might have to have include `nomodset` as well, see https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server

Comment: The tty resolution is still 4K and green